# Is there any way to replace the json filter with dynamic variable value using typescript code

Tags: javascript, ajax, typescript, knockout.js

I have a json filter in which firmwareversion value needs to be replaced with dynamic value. Below is my code:

```
//JSON filter
this.comX200FilterValue = '{ "deviceType": "ComX", "firmwareVersion": "3.5.15" }';

// this is the method which returns the firmwareVersion dynamic value as 3.5.15
          this.deviceService.getFirmwareversion(config.GlobalConstants.Default.comx200Name)
            .then((fwArray: any) => {
              var Com200FirmwareValue = (fwArray[config.GlobalConstants.Default.comx200Name]);
            })
```

I want the filter string (firmware version value : 3.5.15) to be replaced with Com200FirmwareValue.
Something like "firmwareVersion": "Com200FirmwareValue".

Any way to achieve this? Any suggestions would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you convert it to a JSON object using `JSON.parse`, you can edit the object in whatever way you like. If you want to return it to a string, use `JSON.stringify`.

```js
// your string
this.comX200FilterValue = '{ "deviceType": "ComX", "firmwareVersion": "3.5.15" }';
console.log(comX200FilterValue);

// make it a json object and change firmwareVersion
var jsonFilterValue = JSON.parse(this.comX200FilterValue);
jsonFilterValue.firmwareVersion = "Com200FirmwareValue";

// set the stringified version as our original string value
this.comX200FilterValue = JSON.stringify(jsonFilterValue);
console.log(comX200FilterValue);
```